# how to solve java.lang.ClassCastException error

Tags: java, string, swing, jtable, classcastexception

I have designed default table model in JTable properties of swing eclipse. so when i tried to do calculations get error......Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

```
public class punchingPBill extends JFrame
{
    DefaultTableModel model;
    Double rate,discount,amount,exciseduty,outputvat;

    {
        String[] columnNames =  {"Sr.No", "Description Of Goods", "quantity", "Rate", "Per", "Discount", "Basic Excise Duty", "Output Vat", "Amount"};
        Object[][] data = { {new Integer(1),"",new Integer(1), new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0)}};

    model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    }       
        table.setModel(model);
        table.setRowHeight(25);

private void setTableModelListener()
    {
        System.out.println("enter listen");
        TableModelListener tableModelListener = new TableModelListener() 
{
         public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)
            {
               if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE)
                {
                    System.out.println("Cell " + e.getFirstRow() + ", "
                            + e.getColumn() + " changed. The new value: "
                            + table.getModel().getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(),
                                    e.getColumn()));
                    int row = e.getFirstRow();
                    int column = e.getColumn();

                    if(column == 2||column == 3||column == 5)
                    {
                     Integer    quantity = ((Integer) model.getValueAt(row, 2)).intValue();
                   rate = ((Double) model.getValueAt(row, 3)).doubleValue(); 
                   discount=((Double) model.getValueAt(row, 5)).doubleValue();
                   amount=new Double(rate-(quantity*rate*(discount/100)));

                   model.setValueAt(amount, row, 8);

                 }

                }
            }
        };
        table.getModel().addTableModelListener(tableModelListener);
}
```

got errors at- Integer  quantity = ((Integer) model.getValueAt(row, 2)).intValue();.......rate = ((Double) model.getValueAt(row, 3)).doubleValue();......discount=((Double) model.getValueAt(row, 5)).doubleValue();

Comment: _java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer_ seems quite obvious. Search how to convert a String into an Integer. This is quite simple to find.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Integer.parseInt("StringValue") in place of casting where "StringValue" should be a proper number value which can be converted to Integer

Comment: I am not using string at all in program still i got this error for particular cell...so not able to recognize issue

Comment: I can see your data is object array which contains String, Integer, Double etc.


Object Array is also having a empty String. Probably that me the cause of exception. Debug and check

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming below line is throwing this exception:

```
Integer    quantity = ((Integer) model.getValueAt(row, 2)).intValue();
```

Try debugging what is getting returned from `model.getValueAt(row, 2)`, if it returns **String** then you need to use:

```
Integer.parseInt(returnedValueFromMethodCall);
```

Comment: when i tried editing this sale (0,2)...on console i got only this error

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to tell that this happened when you change the value.

Since you are editing the value, it use an JTextComponent (A JTextField most likely) to get the value (the cell showing a cursor), so the result is coming for [`JTextComponent.getText()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText()) as a `String`, not an `Integer`. So you need to parse the value with :

```
Integer.parseInt(string)
```

Of course, this will throw an exception if you input a not integer value.

EDIT : 
You can see the type changement if you print the class of it :

```
System.out.println(model.getValueAt(row, 2));
System.out.println(model.getValueAt(row, 2).getClass());
```

Before you update it, it will output

```
1
Integer
```

After you input anything (let say 2)

```
2
String
```

Here is one way to be sure this will work before and after and edit : (with correct format input, won't work if you input alphabetic value)

```
if (column == 2 || column == 3 || column == 5) {
    Integer quantity = Integer.parseInt(model.getValueAt(row, 2).toString());
    rate = Double.parseDouble(model.getValueAt(row, 3).toString());
    discount = Double.parseDouble(model.getValueAt(row, 5).toString());
    amount = new Double(rate - (quantity * rate * (discount / 100)));

    model.setValueAt(amount, row, 8);
}
```

The solution would be to manage the editing to parse the value directly but this would ask more code

Comment: thank you..but here if i changed 'sr.no' and 'Description Of Goods' it works fine...but when i entered in quantity cell (0,2) and entered " 2 " on console it prints 2 as well as gives this exception also for............ Integer    quantity = ((Integer) model.getValueAt(row, 2)).intValue();

Comment: @Vsal, I don't get your explanation about the column. If you try to input a value in this cell, you get the exception because, as said, the `getValue` is now a `String`, the `Integer` has been override by the editing component return a `String`. This is why you get the exception. It print `2` but as a `String`. See the Edit

Comment: okay got it...so can you just edit if loop...if(column == 2||column == 3||column == 5)
                    {..................................................}

Comment: @Vsal it is a condition, no a loop ;) but it is done, you will see I parse the value, using `.toString()` to be sure I get a `String`, even if it is an `Integer` or `Double`.

Comment: @Vsal Don't forget to accept the answer that match the most your need. This will mark the question as answered.